# Finding nearby locations within a given radius in Android

Tags: android, google-geocoder

I have stored the location for different interesting places in my database. Now I have been trying to implement a button to "Show nearby places" (50km range).

I was wondering how to find the neighboring places within a given range from a selected location. I have taken a look at the GeoCoder class but I could not figure out how to do it.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you have a database of the "neighboring"  places. So can't you just compute the distance from the current location to each of the locations in your database, and show those that are less than 50km away?  I assume you have the GPS coordindates for those places?

Comment: @Larry True, I presume that that is the way to go. The stored places can be anywhere though, meaning that there would be a rather high number of places to check against. I can certainly think of ways of optimizing the algorithm but I wonder if there is a library out there that implements this functionality. Thanks for you comment Larry.

Comment: Btw, Geocoder is used to get an address, or addresses, which describe a given location. For example, if you give it the GPS coordinates of a house, it should return its address. If it is a landmark, it will return the name of the landmark. It may return multiple "names" depending on what is special about that place.  It is not used to return a set of "interesting" places which is what I believe you were trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested, I ended up using PostreSQL and an extension called PostGIS. Places are saved to the database with a PostGIS geography special type column and geo calculations are then made using that data and the user's current location.

It seems to work just fine.